# Proof that a set of vectors can be extented to a basis (but differennt from basis expansion theorem)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set $S={v_i}$ of N vectors in a d ($d<N$) dimensional space (call it V), I know that those vectors span the whole space, but of course they cannot be a basis.

I can expand the space to a bigger space $W = V \oplus A$ so that the dimension of $W$ is N. I need a proof that i can find a orthogonal basis for $W$ so that it's projection on $V$ gives the set $S$.

I already have a proof, but is really ugly and I don't want to use it. Do you know if there is some result in linear algebra that can be used to easily prove this thing?